# Display data from different site collections to a page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, site-collection

I have a  home page in a site collection site A( root site )
and I want to display content here in this page from two different site collections Site B & Site C.

Here what are the approaches to achieve this

1. by development
2. by SharePoint out of the box functionality

Comment: what's the type of data that you need to shown at root site from site B and C

Comment: Also, for future questions - try to specify if the sites are in the same **web application**.  I assume that this is your case, but it always better to make that explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use A `Content Search Web Part` as OOTB solution to Display content from other site collections

[image]

**Note :** The `Content Query WP` is a limited for this purpose it can only display content from one site collection. so you need to use `Content Search Web Part`

For more details check

- [Configure a Content Search Web Part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)
- [Use the Content Search Web Part to display content from other site collections](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929#xsp)